My Banner for cloth simulation only unrolls to half when i pin the vertices of one side
My Banner for cloth simulation only unrolls to half when i pin the vertices of one side. but when i go back into edit mode the banner still shows the full length which it should be

hello could you please share your file?

Might you have pinned both ends accidentally?

yes i can share the file. where can i send you?

read the instructions here: https://blend-exchange.com/ or use another platform like workupload
